# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'steps' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, wizard

I'm trying to make wizards in ReactJS. I'm following an [online tutorial](https://www.cluemediator.com/how-to-create-step-wizard-in-react), however they haven't explained how to make it by multiple pages. So I tried my own way to apply it, but it didn't work.

Here is the code of the first page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";
function NewGame() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(steps[0]);
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
    {
      key: "firstStep",
      label: "My First Step",
      isDone: true,
      component: firstStep,
    },  
  ]);
  const index = steps.findIndex((x) => x.key === activeStep.key);
  setSteps((prevStep) =>
    prevStep.map((x) => {
      if (x.key === activeStep.key) x.isDone = true;
      return x;
    })
  );
 
  const firstStep = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="box">
          <div className="steps">
            <ul className="nav">
              {steps.map((step, i) => {
                return (
                  <li
                    key={i}
                    className={`${
                      activeStep.key === step.key ? "active" : ""
                    } ${step.isDone ? "done" : ""}`}
                  >
                    <div>
                      Step {i + 1}
                      <br />
                      <span>{step.label}</span>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="step-component">{activeStep.component()}</div>
          <div className="btn-component">
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Back"
              onClick={handleBack}
              disabled={steps[0].key === activeStep.key}
            />
            <input
              type="button"
              value={
                steps[steps.length - 1].key !== activeStep.key
                  ? "Next"
                  : "Submit"
              }
              onClick={handleNext}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Form className="column justify-content-center page">
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Benzersiz Ad</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Görünen İsim</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Oyun Açıklaması</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Oyun Türü</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Bireysel</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Oyun Durumu</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
            <Form.Label>Açık</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Link to="/PageTwo">
          <Button className="button" variant="outline-secondary">
            İ L E R İ
          </Button>{" "}
        </Link>
      </div>
    );  
  

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (steps[steps.length - 1].key === activeStep.key) {
      alert("You have completed all steps.");
    }

    setActiveStep(steps[index + 1]);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    const index = steps.findIndex((x) => x.key === activeStep.key);
    if (index === 0) return;

    setSteps((prevStep) =>
      prevStep.map((x) => {
        if (x.key === activeStep.key) x.isDone = false;
        return x;
      })
    );
    setActiveStep(steps[index - 1]);
  };

  };
}
export default NewGame;
```

So when I run this code I have this error in the website:

```
    ReferenceError: Cannot access 'steps' before initialization
NewGame
C:/Users/SAMSUNG/Documents/src/pages/NewGame.js:6
  3 | import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
  4 | import "./style.css";
  5 | function NewGame() {
> 6 |   const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(steps[0]);
  7 |   const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
  8 |     {
  9 |       key: "firstStep",
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

The error is telling you that the variable `steps` is initialized on line 7, but you're using it on line 6 to set the initial value of the `activeStep` state variable. You cannot use a variable before it's initialized, hence the message "Cannot access 'steps' before initialization".

Move line 6 after the statement that begins on line 7.

Comment: here is what i got after i swapped two lines 
×
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'firstStep' before initialization
NewGame
C:/Users/SAMSUNG/src/pages/NewGame.js:11
   8 |     key: "firstStep",
   9 |     label: "My First Step",
  10 |     isDone: true,
> 11 |     component: firstStep,
     | ^  12 |   },  
  13 | ]);
  14 | const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(steps[0]);

Comment: Swapping the two lines is a bad idea, since line 7 continues into lines 8 - 14... Shifting the line to the next available line is probably better advice.

Comment: actually this is exactly what i did 

  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
    {
      key: "firstStep",
      label: "My First Step",
      isDone: true,
      component: firstStep,
    },  
  ]);
  
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(steps[0]);
i havent only swapped two lines
i did shifitng

Comment: @HazalKaya That new ReferenceError is telling you the exact same problem, but with the `firstStep` variable. Interpreting this error message is an important skill for a developer, I recommend you study this error message closely until you understand what it is saying.